# Why doesn't gcc10 see the -fcoroutines flag?

Tags: c++, coroutine, c++20, gcc10

I am trying to compile a program with `#include <coroutine>` header file included in it. But gcc10 throws an error

```
/usr/include/c++/10/coroutine:295:2: error: #error "the coroutine header requires -fcoroutines"
  295 | #error "the coroutine header requires -fcoroutines"
```

I set all the necessary flags in cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.17)
project(cortest1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fcoroutines")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-pthread")

add_executable(cortest1 main.cpp)
```

But the compiler doesn't see the -fcoroutines flag.
I am using g ++ 10.2.0

Comment: use `make VERBOSE=1` to see the actual command; this looks like a cmake configuration error

Comment: `set` sets. It doesn't append.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-pthread")
```

After you set the flags to -pthread, it no longer has the previous value that had the coroutine flag.

P.S. Use target specific configuration i.e. don't set CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS. Use target_compile_options instead. And use target_compile_features instead of setting CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.